# Defining linear transformation: $r:\text{Coker }b \to \text{Coker }c.$ given a commutative sqaure diagram.

Tags: linear-algebra, morphism

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Given the linear transformation $c:X\to Y$ and the commutative square diagram below also with linear transformations $b,c,d.$

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X  \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y \\
\end{array},\quad (1)$$

Show that the linear transformations $a,d$ define a linear transformation $\text{Coker }b  \to  \text{Coker }c$

Attempted solution:

> From the diagram above, I am given $a\cdot c=b\cdot d,$  I then extend the square diagram like below.
>
> $$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X \\
> b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c  \\
> Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y  \\
> q'\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow q  \\
> Y'/\text{Im }b & \xrightarrow{r} & Y/\text{Im }c \\
> \end{array}\quad\quad (2)$$
>
> I think I need to show $r(\text{Coker }b)  \subset  \text{Coker }c,$  in order to show  $\text{Coker }b  \to  \text{Coker }c.$  Elements of $\text{Coker }b$ and $\text{Coker }c$ are respectively $y'+ \text{Im }b$ and   $y+\text{Im }c.$  It is easy to show that the linear transformation $r(\text{Coker }b)$ is well defined.  So let $x'\in X',$ then $(c\cdot a)(x')=(d\cdot b)(x')$
>
> $\Longrightarrow c(a(x'))=d(b(x')),$
>
> $\Longrightarrow c(x)=d(y'),$
>
> But $(r\cdot q')(y')=(q\cdot d)(y')$
>
> $\Longrightarrow r(q'(y'))=q(d(y')),$
>
> and $q'(y')=y'+\text{Im }b\Longrightarrow r(y'+\text{Im }b)=y+\text{Im }c$
>
> Also, $q(d(y'))=q(c(x))=q(y)=y+\text{Im }c$
>
> Hence $r(y'+\text{Im }b)=q(y)=y+\text{Im }c,$ which implies $r(\text{Coker }b)  \subset  \text{Coker }c.$  So the linear transformation we are looking for is $r:\text{Coker }b\to \text{Coker }c.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

Can someone tell me if the way I have shown how the linear transformation defined by $r$ is correct in the sense how I derived it.  I am not certain if the way I did it have shown $r(\text{Coker }b)  \subset  \text{Coker }c.$

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not quite following. You've extended the diagram and said that there is a map $r$ but really this is what you're trying to show exists. When you say "but $r \cdot q' = q \cdot d$" you've already assumed $r$ exists. Note that you do have a straightforward map $Y' \to \text{coker } c$. What you want to say is that you can define $r$ by looking at a preimage of something in $\text{coker } b$ in $Y'$ and then applying $q \cdot d$. What you need to check is that no matter which preimage I pick in $Y'$, this works and so I do have a well defined map $r$

Comment: @OsamaGhani when you say "define $r$ by looking at a preimage of something in coker $b$ in $Y'$.  You mean like let $z^{-1}(y"+\text{Im }b)=y',$ then $(q'\cdot z^{-1})(\{y+\text{Im }b\})=(q'(z^{-1}(\{y'+\text{Im }b\}))=q'(y').$  Then $r\cdot (q'\cdot z^{-1})(\{y+\text{Im }b\})=r(q'(y'))=q(d(y'))\Longrightarrow r(y+\text{Im }b)=q(d(y'))=q(c(x))=q(y)=y+\text{Im }c.$